# Complaints Database Design-SQL Query to show All rows

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have an application where I am showing all complaints to my Logged In agents.
I have 100 of agents who can see the same complaint screen.for example agentA  and agentB
can see all the complaints when they logged in.

```
> Complaint_id  Complaint_detail
        1            complaint_1    
        2            complaint_2    
        3            complaint_3
```

Now the problem is I have to add functionality that every agent can put comments for their ease or you can say a reminder like (agentA put comment : i will work on this comment tomorrow). so this comment will display to only agentA.

for this implementation I have created a new table named complaint_detail where I add coloumn 'comment' and 'user_id'

and to display complaints i write query

```
    select complaint.Complaint_name,complaint.User_ID from complaint 
left outer join complaint_detail on complaint.Complaint_id = complaint_detail.complaint_id
```

this query display all the records now when I filter on user it will show only that users record to solve this I add

```
    select * from (select complaint.Complaint_name,complaint.User_ID from complaint 
left outer join complaint_detail on complaint.Complaint_id = complaint_detail.complaint_id
complaint_detail.complaint_info_id
) asdf
```

where user_id = 'agentA'
or User_ID is null

```
select * from (
select complaints.complaint_id,complaints.complaint_detail,   complaints_detail.comment,complaints_detail.user_id from complaints
left outer join complaints_detail on complaints.Complaint_id = complaints_detail.complaint_id
) asdf
where user_id = 'agentA'
or User_ID is null
```

is

```
complaint_id    complaint_detail    comment        user_id
         1             complaint_1         complaint_1  agentA
         2             complaint_2         complaint_2  agentA
         3             complaint_3           null            null
```

for agentB

```
complaint_id    complaint_detail    comment        user_id
     1             complaint_1          complaint1_ agentB
     3             complaint_3           null            null
```

any idea how can i achieve this that every user can see all complaints and only their comments.should i change table structure or query can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
select * from complaints cmp
left outer join comments com on cmp.id=com.complaint_id
and com.user_id='agentA' or com.user_id is null
```

This will get data from comments table related to complaint if it exists (left join)
and limit comments to those of the agent or without a user id on the comment

Of course you can specify columns in the select if you don't want to retrieve all columns from the complaints & comments tables.

Comment: actually this is my view I cannot pass user Id in this query .I have to get data from my query and filter user on client side.

Comment: So you just need all complaints + comments with the user ID info to filter later?